# How do I share my ethernet connection with my Android phone?

Tags: ethernet, connection-sharing

How can I share my ethernet-connected Ubuntu 14.10 laptop's Internet connection to my Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

Check ["Router - Official Ubuntu Documentation"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) and ["Internet/ConnectionSharing - Official Ubuntu Documentatio..."](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing). I have used the latter in the past to great success.

You would also need to set up an access point, I'd recommend hostapd.